# How do I customize breadcrumbs?

Tags: breadcrumbs

The breadcrumbs I get are like the following ones.

- Service

  HOme

But I want to change them to the following ones.

- Service
  HOme>>Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [theme_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7.x) something like:

```
function yourTheme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
    $output .= '<ul class="breadcrumb">';
    foreach ($breadcrumb as $key => $value) {
      // Remove Br tags
      $output .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul></div></div></div></div>';

    return $output;
  }
}
```

Or if you want just alter the breadcrumb in some pages for example on `node/nid` you can do it in `hook_preprocess_HOOK` or `hook_node_view_alter` something like:

```
function yourModule_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $breadcrumb = array();
  $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), '<front>');
  $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Service'), '/Service');
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. but in which twig.html  page or where we can put this code..

Comment: in your `template.php` of your theme .